# Building libsigc++ fails (std::basic_ostream explicit instantiation)

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, g++, libsigc++

I'm trying to install ardour (http://ardour.org) dependancies on mac os 10.8 (Mountain Lion) according this page: http://ardour.org/building_osx_native.html.

There are two scripts made by ardour devs to do it:

- build-gtk-stack (gtk+, glib, pango, cairo...)
- build-ardour-stack (boost, rapto, libvorbis...)

They can be found in subversion.ardour.org/svn/ardour2/branches/2.0-ongoing/tools/.

I'm getting trouble with the build-ardour-stack script, especially with building libsigc++.

I've got this trace:

```
[...]
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.. -Wall -g -O2 -MT adaptors/lambda/lambda.lo -MD -MP -MF adaptors/lambda/.deps/lambda.Tpo -c adaptors/lambda/lambda.cc  -fno-common -DPIC -o adaptors/lambda/.libs/lambda.o
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -Wall -g -O2 -no-undefined -version-info 0:0:0 -headerpad_max_install_names -o libsigc-2.0.la -rpath /Users/maxime/a3/inst/lib signal.lo signal_base.lo trackable.lo connection.lo functors/slot.lo functors/slot_base.lo adaptors/lambda/lambda.lo
libtool: link: g++ -dynamiclib  -o .libs/libsigc-2.0.0.dylib  .libs/signal.o .libs/signal_base.o .libs/trackable.o .libs/connection.o functors/.libs/slot.o functors/.libs/slot_base.o adaptors/lambda/.libs/lambda.o    -O2   -install_name  /Users/maxime/a3/inst/lib/libsigc-2.0.0.dylib -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1.0 -Wl,-single_module
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libsigc-2.0.dylib" && ln -s "libsigc-2.0.0.dylib" "libsigc-2.0.dylib")
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libsigc-2.0.la" && ln -s "../libsigc-2.0.la" "libsigc-2.0.la" )
Making all in tests
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in examples
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I.. -I..  -Wall -g -O2 -MT hello_world.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/hello_world.Tpo -c -o hello_world.o hello_world.cc
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I.. -I..  -Wall -g -O2 -MT member_method.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/member_method.Tpo -c -o member_method.o member_method.cc
hello_world.cc: In instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’:
hello_world.cc:18:   instantiated from here
hello_world.cc:18: error: explicit instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ but no definition available
hello_world.cc: In instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’:
hello_world.cc:18:   instantiated from here
hello_world.cc:18: error: explicit instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ but no definition available
hello_world.cc: In instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’:
hello_world.cc:18:   instantiated from here
hello_world.cc:18: error: explicit instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ but no definition available
make[2]: *** [hello_world.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mv -f .deps/member_method.Tpo .deps/member_method.Po
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
libsigcpp build failed
```

hello_world.cc :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sigc++/sigc++.h>

SIGC_USING_STD(cout)
SIGC_USING_STD(endl)
SIGC_USING_STD(string)

void on_print(const std::string& str)
{
  std::cout << str;
}

int main()
{
  sigc::signal<void, const std::string&> signal_print;
  signal_print.connect( sigc::ptr_fun(&on_print) );
  signal_print.emit("hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

My gcc is:

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00).
```

What do you think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I asked libsigc++ devs using their mailing-list. I post here the solutions they asked me to try. In my case none of them did resolve the problem :

- remove SIGC_USING_STD macros
- -std=c++0x compiler flag
- comment the hello_world.cc out in the makefile

I also tried to add the following option to the compiler : -mmacosx-version-min=10.8.

I heard some other people did success in compiling what I try to. It was under the same version of mac os (10.8). So it seems the problem comes from my part...