# Mex files on Mountain Lion: explicit instantiation error

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm working with MATLAB r2012b on Mountain Lion, and XCode version installed is 4.6.1. I've also used the patch at http://www.mathworks.it/support/solutions/en/data/1-IXBVKD/ and then I have typed "mex - setup" and selected the only option available

```
1: /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin/mexopts.sh : Template Options file for building gcc MEX-files
```

I'm trying to use a framework for sparse modeling (written in C++) which uses mex files. In order to install the previous framework I have to call a matlab file inside the framework which calls mex function: however when I call this function I get the following message...

```
compilation of: -I./linalg/ -I./decomp/ -I./dictLearn/ dictLearn/mex/mexTrainDL.cpp
./linalg/linalg.h: In member function 'void Matrix<T>::print(const std::string&) const [with T = float]':
./linalg/linalg.h:1084:   instantiated from 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'
./linalg/linalg.h:1084:   instantiated from 'void Matrix<T>::print(const std::string&) const [with T = float]'
dictLearn/mex/mexTrainDL.cpp:197:   instantiated from here
./linalg/linalg.h:1084: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' but no definition available
./linalg/linalg.h: At global scope:
./linalg/linalg.h: In instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]':
./linalg/linalg.h:1084:   instantiated from 'void Matrix<T>::print(const std::string&) const [with T = float]'
dictLearn/mex/mexTrainDL.cpp:197:   instantiated from here
./linalg/linalg.h:1084: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' but no definition available
./linalg/linalg.h: In instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]':
./linalg/linalg.h:1084:   instantiated from 'void Matrix<T>::print(const std::string&) const [with T = float]'
dictLearn/mex/mexTrainDL.cpp:197:   instantiated from here
./linalg/linalg.h:1084: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' but no definition available

mex: compile of ' "dictLearn/mex/mexTrainDL.cpp"' failed.
```

The problem is not connected to the framework. Googling I have seen that I'm not the only one with this problem with matlab, but I don't know how to fix it. Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Mattia

UPDATE:

I've discovered that the error is produced by the following blocks of code

Block 1:

```
/// print the sparse matrix
template<typename T> inline void SpMatrix<T>::print(const string& name) const {
    cerr << name << endl;
    cerr << _m << " x " << _n << " , " << _nzmax << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<_n; ++i) {
        for (int j = _pB[i]; j<_pE[i]; ++j) {
            cerr << "(" <<_r[j] << "," << i << ") = " << _v[j] << endl;
        }
     }
};
```

Block 2

```
/// Print the matrix to std::cout
template <typename T> inline void Matrix<T>::print(const string& name) const {
   std::cerr << name << std::endl;
   std::cerr << _m << " x " << _n << std::endl;
   for (int i = 0; i<_m; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j<_n; ++j) {
         printf("%10.5g ",static_cast<double>(_X[j*_m+i]));
         //         std::cerr << _X[j*_m+i] << " ";
      }
      printf("\n ");
      //std::cerr << std::endl;
   }
   printf("\n ");
};
```

Block 3

```
template <typename T> void ShiftMatrix<T>::print(const string& name) const {
   cerr << name << endl;
   cerr << "Shift Matrix: " << _shifts << " shifts" << endl;
   _inputmatrix->print(name);
};
```

And block 4

```
template <typename T> void DoubleRowMatrix<T>::print(const string& name) const {
   cerr << name << endl;
   cerr << "Double Row Matrix" << endl;
   _inputmatrix->print(name);
};
```

and the error is always due to the first line of the above blocks, that is ...

```
cerr << name << endl;
```

Commenting the above line in the 4 blocks the compiling terminates successfully.

Does somebody know why this happens?

Comment: What is on the line ./linalg/linalg.h:1083? What headers are included in that file? Sounds like maybe it has a forward declaration (e.g., from `<iosfwd>`) but not the full definition of the class template.

Comment: Hi, at line 1083 there is 'std::cerr << name << std::endl;', and the include statements are #ifndef LINALG_H
#define LINALG_H

#include "misc.h"
#ifdef USE_BLAS_LIB
#include "cblas_alt_template.h"
#else
#include "cblas_template.h"   // this is obsolete
#endif
#include <fstream>
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include <string>
#else
#include <cstring>
#endif
#include <list>
#include <vector>

#ifdef NEW_MATLAB
   typedef ptrdiff_t INTT;
#else
   typedef int INTT;
#endif

#include <utils.h>

Comment: At first sight it looks like the author has not included <iostream> which contains stderr, but when I compiled on Snow Leopard and with a previous version of Xcode (and Matlab 2012a) there were no problems!!!

Comment: Seems like maybe fstream used to include iostream but doesn't any more. The solution may be as simple as changing that file to include it.

Comment: I've tried to add #include <iostream> to linalg.h but the same error occurs.

Comment: I've posted (up in the question) the full error (before I had posted only the last part of it). The strange thing it's that with Snow Leopard and a previous version of Xcode there were no problems!!! Now the error is on line 1084, instead of 1083, because I've added the #include <iostream> statement.

Comment: Hmm. Can you comment out all the cin/cout/cerr statements in that file and see if it works?

Comment: I've tried to comment the above line and there was another error of the same type, so I commented also this one and I had the same error at another line and then at onother line. However when I commented all the 4 lines that gave all the error above, then there were no another errors and compiling terminated successfully. I've noted that the 4 lines that produce the error above are all of the same type: there is an inline function and the error is produced by the following line, where there is a 'cerr<<argumentOfTheInlineFunction<<endl'.

Comment: @metal I've added an example of the code that produces the error in the Question above, under 'UPDATE:'. Maybe you know why that statement produces the above error ...

Comment: Ahh, do you have `#include <string>` in that file? I don't think it has anything to do with the inline keyword.

Comment: Yes, there is '#include <cstring>'. I've updated the question above with all the 4 blocks of file linalg.h producing the error. You are right: inline statement is not the problem since inline compares in only 2 of the 4 blocks and also because I've tried to remove the inline statement and the same error happens while compiling.

Comment: @metal If you work on a Mac maybe I could give you the link to the framework so that you can try to compile it on your machine. The only think to do it would be to put the frameowork folder inside matlab and start the matlba file compile.m!

Comment: Note that I am talking about `<string>` not `<cstring>`. (I don't have access to a Mac, sorry.)

Comment: There is also 'include <string>'. I posted all the include statement in the second comment to my question.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Forgot about that, and it's hard to read. Can you add command line options to the compile process? If so, try having it save its preprocessor output, then look through there for the explicit instantiation of cerr and the definition of std::basic_ostream.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by adding the compile flag  "-mmacosx-version-min=10.7" via the line

```
compile_flags=[compile_flags ' -mmacosx-version-min=10.7'];
```

in the SPAMS framework's compile.m immediately before the for block that calls mex.

This solution came from [Trying to build muParser: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream but no definition available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748504/trying-to-build-muparser-error-explicit-instantiation-of-stdbasic-ostream-b) and [Building libsigc++ fails (std::basic_ostream explicit instantiation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233978/building-libsigc-fails-stdbasic-ostream-explicit-instantiation) which appear to be the same problem with other packages.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem by changing the MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.5' to '10.6' in mexopts.sh.